Facebook catalog ads utm issue
Im running facebook ads catalog > carousal format. But visitors are unable to access my website, there some bad url. But whenever i am create catalog collection format then visitors can visit.
I am using g.analytics and tag manager. After changing these tools i am getting issue.
